# WSO2 ESB 5.0.0 Datamapper error is not launching fault sequence

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I'm trying to use datamapper for transforming the incoming message, the problem is, when the message is different from expected it literally ends up the execution without calling the fault sequence that I've defined for the sequence. Is there a solution for this? How can I deal with mapping errors?

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: is this a json or xml message?

Comment: XML Message, I can control the response code but what happens if the mapping changes and I'm not aware of it, this could be a problem. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

`DataMapper mediator` as of now does not perform a validation against the schema. When the mapping cannot be performed due to incompatible input, the execution fails. Since you have an XML payload, you can use a `Validate mediator` before the `DataMapper` to verify that the payload adheres to the expected XML schema. Refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Validate+Mediator for more details. By specifying the fault path in `Validate mediator`, you can solve your mentioned problem.